# Circles are squares, day is night, dogs and cats living together... all-around weirdness

Tags: bug, layout

Something weird is happening. I happened to be using Internet Explorer (please don't judge me, I'm just evading StayFocusd on Chrome...), and this is what I see (click for bigger view):

[image]

Things are just generally all out of whack. The counters for moderator flags, edits, and notifications are all squares, lines seem kind of generally *thicker*, I guess, and there is extra space everywhere. Tags don't have parentheses around them. The community bulletin box is weird.

---

Here is what the user page looks like:

[image]

---

Here is what the moderator flag queue looks like (pixelated for users' privacy):

[image]

This is Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7.

Comment: Note that the parenthesis around tag names are missing too. Have you tried hard refresh (Ctrl+F5)?

Comment: Looks like Ctrl+F5 doesn't help (also I mentioned the parentheses issue)

Comment: Most of the IE versions on Browsershots.org [seem to be doing fine](http://browsershots.org/http://math.stackexchange.com/) (e.g. [IE 10 on Windows 8](http://i.stack.imgur.com/czzqf.png), [IE 9 on Windows 2008 Server](http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/cd/cd7ef59fb6431e707a2956aa55b40be7.png)). Are you sure you're not using [IE 6 on Windows XP](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZoNT.png)? :)

Comment: Also what's the point of installing StayFocusd if you have another browser? That's like doing [speedballs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedball_%28drug%29) in order to avoid drinking!

Comment: A disaster of Biblical proportions: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3ZOKDmorj0